# Does Google Crawl Rate have an impact on Google's Image Bot

Tags: web-crawlers, googlebot, google-image-search

I have a relatively large website. Each page has several images. Google indexes my website very slowly, but it actively crawls my pictures. Does changing the Google Crawl Rate have an impact on Google's Image Bot? In other words, does Google's Crawl Rate only affect the Google Bot or does it affect the Google Image Bot as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup crawl rate for certain bot in your robots.txt, like

```
User-agent: Googlebot-Image/1.0
Crawl-delay: 10
```

Comment: [No version of Googlebot has ever supported the `crawl-delay` directive in robots.txt](https://www.youtube.com/watch?reload=9&v=ZSghHC_4LzU) as far as I know.  Google says that [using Search Console is the only way to slow down Googlebot](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/4862).  They don't have a separate setting for Googlebot-Image there, however.   This question seems to be asking whether or not that setting applies to both Googlebot and Googlebot-Image.

Comment: You have to be careful when using a new `User-agent` section in robots.txt.   If you use one, the bot will then completely ignore the `User-agent: *` section.   That is true even if the specific section only has a crawl delay.  To make this work you would have to copy all your `Disallow` directives there and make sure to keep them up to date with all changes. See on StackOverflow [Robots.txt - What is the proper format for a Crawl Delay for multiple user agents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17377835/robots-txt-what-is-the-proper-format-for-a-crawl-delay-for-multiple-user-agent)

Comment: @StephenOstermiller There is something opposite meanings in the youtube video you cited and the SO topic from `@unor`: first means no, second means yes. I tend to the second meaning - however never used it myself.